# cant use ActionBar methods in android studio

Tags: android

I am trying to set some things to the action bar but i get the same errors on any method i use for it (e.g `actionBar.setTitle("my title");` or  `actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.actionbar_draw);`)

i cant even use the get methods for it...

they all give this error:

```
required android.support.v7.app.ActionBar but found android.app.ActionBar
```

i am using minimum sdk 15 and this is my code:

```
    package com.tos.test.testactionbarapp;

    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("my title");


    }
}
```

problem is, my app crashes whenever i start it because of this code and i get:

```
                                                                         ---
```

`------ beginning of crash
05-28 15:32:00.403 11476-11476/ccom.tos.test.testactionbarapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.tos.test.testactionbarapp, PID: 11476
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tos.test.testactionbarapp/com.tos.test.testactionbarapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.app.ActionBar.getTitle()' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.app.ActionBar.getTitle()' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at com.tos.test.testactionbarapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)`

Comment: you should use Toolbar replace ActionBar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar` and use `getSupportActionBar()` method od activity.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
getActionBar();
```

to

```
getSupportActionBar();
```

Try it!!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setTitle("my title");


}
```

Comment: thank you all very much, i used                                                    getSupportActionBar();                                                                                and not it works well but what is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Just Do this

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

instead of

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
```

Comment: the compiler suggested to migrate it to this:   android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); and now it works fine , but why is it like that? i followed the instructions from here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html

Comment: getASupported action bar eextends from the class android.support.v7.app.ActionBar. so if you use getSupport action bar you have to do like this or import this class